# Send email django from any host

Tags: python, django, email, django-models

I have read plenty of links for sending emails through django. I've tried all of them but they don't work. I tried sending an email through the python shell and I get '1'. 
- So what are the settings that I should use for the email to work, I'm willing to use any mail server?
- I was using gmail but I read that it causes problems, if I'm going to use hotmail for example do I need to specify the email password in the settings.xml?
- how to debug this problem?

Comment: Have you specified all necessay settings that are required? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/

Comment: I used the following settings: MAIL_USE_TLS ,EMAIL_HOST ,EMAIL_PORT ,EMAIL_HOST_USER ,EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD ,EMAIL_BACKEND ,EMAIL_FILE_PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pure python code for sending emails using SMTP Lib

```
from threading import Thread
import requests
import time
import smtplib
def email_sender(input_message, email_to, client):
    ''' function to send email '''
    to = email_to
    gmail_user = 'email of sender account'
    gmail_pwd = 'password of sender account'
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
    smtpserver.ehlo()
    smtpserver.starttls()
    smtpserver.ehlo
    smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:site down! \n'
    input_message = input_message + client
    msg = header + input_message
    smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
    smtpserver.close()
```

Comment: GREAT it's working, I had to enable access of gmail from less secure apps  in the settings. Thank you. If I'm using another mail server do I need to change something

Comment: Whatever I write in the input_message , I receive an empty email. I tried to hard code a message but it doesn't get sent I use input_message='TEST'

Comment: You need to add '\n' before the message body

Answer (score 1):

You can try yagmail, it should make it a lot easier:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.Connect('user@gmail.com', 'password')
yagmail.send(email_to, subject = 'site down!', contents = 'with some error')
```

It has a lot more features, for example how to make it easier to send attachments etc.

yagmail can be found at [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

You will probably have to install it first using pip:

```
pip install yagmail  # python 2
pip3 install yagmail # python 3
```

Comment: Thanks but I want it to work also for other domains, not only gmail.

Comment: @PokaYoke It works on SMTP. So you can basically do any domain: `yagmail.Connect('user@gmail.com', 'password', host = 'mydomain', port = 1337)`

Comment: the name "yagmail" made me think it works for gmail only. For my application I prefer not to install extra libraries because I'm working with many people, and I don't want to deal with the "it's not working on my machine" hassle.